# Facing Error while deploy the serving function in mlrun

Tags: mlrun, nuclio

I had instal mlrun with kubernates, i had tried the to execute the 02-model training tutorial code in jupyter-lab, so everything works fine till model serving, then i tried to deploy the serving function then it shows as error listed bellow :

Failed to deploy. Details:

```
Error - the server could not find the requested resource
    ...//nuclio/pkg/platform/kube/functionres/lazy.go:757

Call stack:
Failed to create resource
    ...//nuclio/pkg/platform/kube/functionres/lazy.go:757
Failed to create/update HPA
    ...//nuclio/pkg/platform/kube/functionres/lazy.go:230
Failed to create/update function
    .../platform/kube/controller/nucliofunction.go:213

> 2023-01-17 18:42:53,721 [error] Nuclio function failed to deploy: {'function_state': 'error'}
```

error in nuclio.. please help me regarding this

Comment: Did you have the same issue with compose (in desktop docker)? Which mlrun version did you use?

Answer (score 1):

This might have to do with Nuclio version, before 1.11.16, supported HPA version was v2beta1, which is not supported from K8s 1.24.11 version